# UNIX FIFO: the process hangs if I don't close the input side of the fifo

Tags: c, unix, fifo

I've just started working with UNIX FIFOs, and I discovered something while experimenting with my first FIFO program. The program works this way: after creating the FIFO, two processes are started using the `fork()` function. The child process reads what the father passes to him through the FIFO, and prints it on the screen. The data exchanged is the string specified as an argument. The question is: in the father section, if I forget to close the input side of the FIFO (meaning that I exclude the `close(fd)` line) the program would just hang, even if the data between the processes is exchanged correctly. Otherwise, everything works fine and the program terminates withouth hanging. Can someone please explain me why?

Thanks for your patience. Here is the code of the main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("An argument must be specified\n");
        return -1;
    }   

    int ret = mkfifo("./fifo.txt", 0644);
    char buf;

    if(ret < 0)
    {
        perror("Error creating FIFO");
        return -1;
    }

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if(pid < 0)
    {
        perror("Error creating child process");
        return -1;
    }

    if(pid == 0) /* child */
    {
        int fd = open("./fifo.txt", O_RDONLY); /* opens the fifo in reading mode */

        while(read(fd, &buf, 1) > 0)
        {
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, 1);
        }
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", 1);
        close(fd);
        return 0;
    }
    else /* father */
    {
        int fd = open("./fifo.txt", O_WRONLY); /* opens the fifo in writing mode */

        write(fd, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
        close(fd);
        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be that the child process stucks becouse it's waiting for the father to close the FIFO, but since the father doesn't do that the child waits forever for the FIFO to be closed, while the father waits as well for the child to terminate?

Answer (score 5):

`read(2)` blocks until there are characters available or the channel is closed at the other end.  The father process must close the pipe in order for the last child `read()` to return.  If you omit the `close(fd)` in the father, the child will block  in the `read()` until the father exits (closing the pipe automatically) but father will hang in `waitpid()` until the child exits.

Comment: Of course you're right, how could I not get that before! The read() function won't return 0 until the parent process on the other side of the FIFO closes it. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First things first: there are several issues with the code you posted.

1. There are no `#include` directives, hence no prototypes in scope for any of the functions you call.  C89 requires prototypes for variadic functions such as `printf()`; C99 requires prototypes for *all* functions.  Both C89 and C99 require declarations in scope for `O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY`, `STDOUT_FILENO` and `NULL`.
2. `-1` is not an allowed return value for `main()`.
3. C89 does not allow mixing declarations and statements.

A minor nit: the usual nomenclature is "parent and child", not "father and child".

I have modified your program to correct this issue and improve readability:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("An argument must be specified\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int ret = mkfifo("./fifo.txt", 0644);
    char buf;

    if (ret < 0) {
        perror("Error creating FIFO");
        return 1;
    }

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("Error creating child process");
        return 1;
    }

    if (pid == 0) { /* child */
        int fd = open("./fifo.txt", O_RDONLY); /* opens the fifo in reading mode */

        while(read(fd, &buf, 1) > 0) {
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, 1);
        }
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", 1);
        close(fd);
        return 0;
    } else { /* parent */
        int fd = open("./fifo.txt", O_WRONLY); /* opens the fifo in writing mode */

        write(fd, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
        close(fd);
        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

But most importantly, you did not mention what operating system and compiler you are using.

I am unable to reproduce the issue, and I suspect it may be related to one of the issues listed above.

Comment: Bah, of course I am unable to reproduce your problem - I compiled and ran the program as listed instead of removing the `close()` statement as you specified. What JeremyP said.

Comment: JeremyP, it is either C89 or C99 or some dialect derived from one or the other; in any case, the program will not compile as listed even with the most forgiving of compilers due to missing declarations (or macro definitions) for `O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY`, `STDOUT_FILENO` and `NULL`.

Comment: Of course my code also included the necessary include directives, otherwise it would have never compiled. I decided to quote only the main function for a matter of brevity. Anyway, thanks a lot for your advices, honestly I didn't know the return value of the main function wasn't allowed to be -1. The operating system I'm using is Ubuntu 10.04, the compiler is GCC version 4.4.3.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't disputing your point that the code won't compile as listed in the question. It was really just your point 3 about mixing declarations and code seemed a bit severe since it holds for C89 but not C99 which everybody has now except people using Visual Studio and for them, this whole question is irrelevant.

Comment: I didn't get that about `main` not being allowed to return `-1` . What is the basis for this?

Comment: The C standard allows 0, `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` (C99 §5.1.2.2.3 and §7.20.4.3). POSIX expands this to “any other value”, but in practice only 0-255 can be used because of the way it is delivered to the parent process.